# binding to an property of built-in control within custom usercontrol from another usercontrol

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

Due to the origin MainWindow.xaml was too large, really difficult to maintain. so I separate them into several User Controls. However I encountered the following issue, one control in UserControl_2 is refer to ListView's selection within UserControl_1. I tried to alter the binding, but none of them working as expected. Any idea how to binding to another User Control correctly?

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow" ...>
    <Grid>
        <view:UserControl_1/>
        <view:UserControl_2/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

UserControl_1.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.views.UserControl_1 ...>
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="MyListView" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl_2.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.views.UserControl_2 ...>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Test"
            Command="TestCommand"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=MyListView.SelectedIndex,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl_1}}}"
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Probably a cleaner approach to keep the list and the button that references it together in the same user control.

Comment: Declare a SelectedIndex dependency property in UserControl_1 and a CommandParameter dependency property in UserControl_2. Bind them to the respective UI elements by RelativeSource bindings (inside their respective XAML). In MainWindow, bind UserControl_2.CommandParameter to UserControl_1.SelectedIndex.

Comment: Your problem comes from the fact that your design is poor. UserControls should encompass reusable bits of UI and should be designed like any other control (e.g., a TextBox has a Text property you can bind to) or be designed for specific models/view models for use in DataTemplating (e.g., a PersonEditor for a Person). Don't use UserControls to slice your UI into smaller chunks. Those slices can cross concerns and hinder cohesion, as you have found.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view model class and set this one as the `DataContext` of the parent window:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private int _selectedIndex;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set { _selectedIndex = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow" ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <view:UserControl_1/>
        <view:UserControl_2/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You can then bind the `ListView` and the `Button` in the user controls to the same source property.

**UserControl_1.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.views.UserControl_1 ...>
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="MyListView" SelectedIndex="{Binding DataContext.SelectedIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl_2.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.views.UserControl_2 ...>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Test"
            Command="TestCommand"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedIndex,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```